# Creating mysql query with count joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a mysql query to get some data joining 3 different tables. The tables are **users**, **activities** and **reactions**.

Users are creating activities and users are making reactions on any activity. What I want to achieve is to retrieve all the **users**, sorted with the number of reactions **received** totally on their activities.

Sample tables are shown below among with their important columns that we need to consider in our join query.

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 |
| 2 | User 2 |
| 3 | User 3 |
| 4 | User 4 |
| 5 | User 5 |
| 6 | User 6 |
| 7 | User 7 |

**activities**

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |

**reactions**

| activity_id | user_id | reaction_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

**Sample desired Result**

| user_id | reactions_received |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

After researching and trying several queries with joins, I ended up with something that I think is somehow close to what I want:

My query:

```
SELECT u.id, count(a.id) as reactions_received  
FROM users u  
JOIN activities a ON u.id=a.user_id  
JOIN reactions r ON a.id=r.activity_id  
GROUP BY r.user_id  
ORDER BY reactions_received DESC"
```

I also tried to replace the column within count() with other columns but the result remains the same.

Using the above query I managed to get the correct reactions_received (number of reactions) grouped by users, but the u.id gives me always one specific user id (i.e. 1)

**Sample Result I get**

| user_id | reactions_received |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

The number of reactions is correctly split but I want the query to give me the correct user-reactions mapping for example:

| user_id | reactions_received |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |

Thank you

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. I'd do GROUP BY u.id.

Comment: Your query would error in any other RDBMS (as well Mysql 5.7+). Do as jarlh suggests and change to `GROUP BY u.id` and maybe also upgrade your mysql version and don't use the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY = False` so strange sql like this will error as it should.

Comment: `SELECT r.user_id, count(r.activity_id) as countreactions 
FROM wp_users u 
JOIN wp_bp_activity a ON u.ID=a.user_id
JOIN wp_vkreact_activity_user_reaction r ON a.id=r.activity_id 
WHERE a.type='activity_update' 
AND a.user_id = u.ID
GROUP BY r.user_id 
ORDER BY countreactions DESC"`



Updated my query gives correctly separate user_id on the results. However, the count gives me the number of reactions **made by the user** and not the number of reactions received on their activities.